# Sharing /home partition between Linux OSs

Tags: partitioning, fstab

I've been using Ubuntu as my main OS for a while, but I read about Elementary OS and I wanted to try it so I installed it.

I wanted to share /home partition between both OSs but I forgot to do it when installing, so I let it finish the installation process and then proceeded to change fstab. Too bad that when I finished the modification and rebooted to apply the changes it broke Elementary's beauty UI! It was showing me an ugly one -- I think it was the X11 -- so I decided to reinstall sharing partitions from the beginning just in case it would finally work... but it didn't.

I think this is caused by sharing /home partition because before I changed fstab it worked nicely, but not after. Maybe this is related to some UI information Ubuntu saves in the ~ directory?

Well, I don't know, but the fact is that there's something that's interfering with Elementary UI. Can you think of anything that would cause this -- and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing home dir is not best solution. Your $HOME contains dotfiles that determine UI and behavior of some applications.

It would be better to mount home of your main OS to Elementary /media/, and then use soft links to directories with your files.

You can also create links for some single config files, like .bashrc, .emacs and so on.

Also vitalization is useful if you are interested in testing different operation systems.